# How to invoke/execute Maya menu item using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, maya, autodesk, mel

I would like to learn how to invoke/trigger a menu bar item in Maya using python.

For example, opening the "content browser" dialog window from menu bar:Windows->General Editors->Content Browser.

Appreciate any hints on this!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable "Echo all commands" in the script editor, you can see which commands are executed if you choose a menu item, in this case it is:

```
OpenContentBrowser;
```

So from python you can try it with pymel:

```
import pymel.core as pm
pm.mel.OpenContentBrowser()
```

Or with cmds:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.OpenContentBrowser()
```

Comment: Thank You! Do you recommend learning Mel instead of Python? Are there any resources  you would recommend on converting Mel to Python?

Comment: No, python is much better in most cases, but some command in maya are only avalilabel as mel commands, not as python commands.